# Dealing with multiple flags via getopt

Tags: bash

I am using a script which should be invoked using only a single parameter to each flag as follows:

```
./testit.sh -n 123 -t tvar -b bvar -s svar my_program.exe flags to my program
```

where all flags are just flags to the script, and the script will launch `my_program.exe` with the flags `flags to my program`. The simple method being used to do this is `getopts` as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
# contents of "test_it.sh"
echo "\$* = "$*

getopt_out=`getopt t:T:b:B:s:S:n:N $*`
echo "getopt_out = "$getopt_out

echo "\$* = "$*

set -- `getopt t:T:b:B:s:S:n:N $*`
echo "\$* = "$*

while [ $1 != -- ]; do
  shift
done
shift

echo "**********************************************************************************"
echo "*** The program I want to run is: "$*
echo "**********************************************************************************"
```

where the (correct) output is:

```
**********************************************************************************
*** The program I want to run is: my_program.exe flags to my program
**********************************************************************************
```

I, however, need to send multiple numerical options to `-n` as follows:

```
./testit.sh -n 123 456 789 -t tvar -b bvar -s svar my_program.exe flags to my program
```

which gives incorrect output:

```
**********************************************************************************
*** The program I want to run is: 456 789 my_program.exe flags to my program
**********************************************************************************
```

How can I, from within 'testit.sh', get rid of those extra numbers? I am able to deal with them (log their values) at the beginning of the script so that they are no longer needed. Since the `testit.sh` script relies on `shift`, is there a way for me to completely disregard (throw out) the numeric values without messing up the flow of the commands, so that `shift` can still be used?

EDIT: Upon further investigation of my original script, I noticed that the output of `getopts` is different than the one posted in my minimal example. I have updated the minimal example along with the proposed workaround in an answer, though I would appreciated other (probably more canonical and/or correct) methods for dealing with this).

Comment: If you need `123 456 789` to be a single argument to the `-n` flag then you need to quote that in the call and start using `"$@"` instead of `$*` to support safe usage of quoted strings, etc. Additionally, you need to make sure that your `getopt(1)` is the util-linux version and not operating in compatible mode.

Comment: Thank you - I will think about those things. For this question, however, I am primarily concerned with how to deal with this internally from `testit.sh`. That is - assuming that I cannot alter the way that the `testit.sh` script is called, but only what flags are passed to it.

Comment: You get to manually walk what's left in the positional parameters and shift away anything that comes before the program you want to run I think. Though getopt does, I think I just saw, support a way of getting it to not re-arrange non-option arguments. If that still puts `--` after the last flag (I don't see how it could) that might be of use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the original script which was causing me problems actually used `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` which slightly changes the order of `--` in the output. I have posted the new code (including `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1`), along with my workaround for anyone who is interested:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "\$* = "$*

POSIXLY_CORRECT=1
export POSIXLY_CORRECT

getopt_out=`getopt t:T:b:B:s:S:n:N: $*`
echo "getopt_out = "$getopt_out

set -- `getopt t:T:b:B:s:S:n:N: $*`
echo "\$* = "$*

double_dash_too_soon=false
while [ $1 != -- ]; do
  echo "\$1 = "$1
  case $1 in
    -t) 
      # process this flag
      shift
      ;;  
    -b) 
      # process this flag
      shift
      ;;  
    -s) 
      # process this flag
      shift
      ;;  
    -n) 
      This_num=$2
      echo "This_num = "$This_num
      shift
      while [[ $2 != "-"[a-z,A-Z] ]] ; do
        echo "Dealing with number!"
        if [[ $1 == "--" ]]; then
          echo "WARNING: '--' encountered during numeric reads!!" >&2
          double_dash_too_soon=true
        fi  
        shift
      done
      ;;  
  esac
  shift

  if [ "$double_dash_too_soon" == true ]; then
    double_dash_too_soon=false
    echo "(1) \$* -> "$*
    set -- `getopt t:T:b:B:s:S:n:N $*`
    echo "(2) \$* -> "$*
  fi  

done
shift

echo "**********************************************************************************"
echo "*** The program I want to run is: "$*
echo "**********************************************************************************"
```